Any way to change values in OpenAPI spec based on selected server?
In my OpenAPI Description, I have multiple servers defined like:
servers:
- url: /stuff/api/v1
  description: Production
- url: /api/v1
  description: Test

We have a server that is hosting the Swagger UI (which references our open API spec files to document endpoints).
In our server we host other kinds of documentation (like PDF files or other downloadable content).  These can be referenced in our Open API Spec documents using markdown links, and when rendered in the Swagger UI allow users to click the link and download stuff.
Production servers are behind a couple proxies which means the relative path changes vs when we run locally or on test servers.
E.g. I'd like the markdown link to be like:
[Something](relative/path/thing.txt)

if the selected server is the Test server, and something like
[Something](../foo/relative/path/thing.txt)

if the selected server is Production.
As it stands, I have to do something like this:
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: My Endpoint
  version: '1.0'
  description: |
    ## Title
    Blah blah...

    ---
    [A File - PRODUCTION](../openapi/stuff/file.yaml)
    *(use this link if deployed in PRODUCTION)*

    [A File - TEST](openapi/stuff/file.yaml)
    *(use this link if deployed in TEST)*


this is a swagger-ui feature request.  tbh, it's highly unlikely they will support modifying markdown links in descriptions.  Because you're looking for a real-time UI based solution, I would look into contributing an extension or forking the project and modifying the behavior on your own. www.github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui

@JeremyFiel, thank you.  I suspected so, but thought I'd ask in case I was missing something really cool.

Your question is not super clear how you want them to change, but have you considered using variables in the server object?
They can be used in the root, path or operation
root
openapi: 3.1.0
info:
  title: test
  version: 0.0.1
servers:
- url: https://{{domain}}.example.org/v1
  variables:
    domain:
      description: this is the domain variable
      enum:
      - prod
      - test
      default: prod
paths: {}

path
openapi: 3.1.0
info:
  title: test
  version: 0.0.1
paths:
  '/thing':
    servers:
    - url: https://{{domain}}.example.org/v1
      variables:
        domain:
        description: this is the domain variable
        enum:
        - prod
        - test
        default: prod

operation
openapi: 3.1.0
info:
  title: test
  version: 0.0.1
paths:
  '/thing':
    get:
      servers:
      - url: https://{{domain}}.example.org/v1
        variables:
          domain:
          description: this is the domain variable
          enum:
          - prod4567
          - test
          default: prod4567
    post:
      servers:
      - url: https://{{domain}}.example.org/v1
        variables:
          domain:
          description: this is the domain variable
          enum:
          - prod123
          - test
          default: prod123


You're right, my question wasn't clear. I updated it.  I don't think variables will necessarily help me in this case, since I want to use them outside of path references (like a markdown link in a description block).
